# How to change the visibility of div tags which are accessed with class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning,

i want to improve the userexperience. So i want to slide out content if the User clicks on the arrow and the surrounding box of the arrow. But at the moment the user just can click on the Arrow but not on the box.

The **Html** looks like this:

```
    <div class="ALL">
       <img src="~/Images/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp.png" alt="Arrow" id="Arrow_up" style= "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />
       <img src="~/Images/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp.png" alt="Arrow" id="Arrow_down" style= "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" /> 

       <div id="Part_of_ALL">
        @Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)
       </div>

    </div>
```

The **old** **javascript** where the user just can click on the arrows to pull the box up or down:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Arrow_down').hide();
  $('#Arrow_up').show();
  $('#escalation_model').hide();

  $('#Arrow_up').click(function () {    //change here to .ALL
      $(".ALL").switchClass("ALL", "ALL_open",0);
      $('#Arrow_up').hide();
      $('#Arrow_down').show();
      $('#Part_of_ALL').show();            
  });

  $('#Arrow_down').click(function () {    //change here to .ALL_open
      $(".ALL_open").switchClass("ALL_open", "ALL", 0);
      $('#Arrow_up').show();
      $('#Arrow_down').hide();
      $('#Part_of_ALL').hide();

  });
 });
```

So, now i thought to achieve my goal i just have to change the activation of the click function of the id="Arrow_down/up" to my class ALL and ALL_open, but that wont work. It can open the box, but dont react on my closing actions. I also tried it with toggle all things, because its a shorter javascript but that didnt work either.
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: which box are you talking about? if you want to make something appear like a box then wrap the img within a span and style it

Comment: by `switchClass` do u mean `toggleClass` ?

Comment: Its the box with the id="Part_of_ALL". I changed it to a span now, but its the same problem. its appearing but wont disaapear.      @RRR if i would reduce the third part of the javascript i would use that function, but at the moment it switches in the second part the class to ALL_open and in the third part back to ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toggle() like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Arrow_down, #Part_of_ALL').hide();
  $('#Arrow_up').show();
  $('#escalation_model').hide();

  $('.ALL').click(function() { //change here to .ALL
    $(this).switchClass("ALL", "ALL_open", 0);
    $('#Arrow_up, #Arrow_down, #Part_of_ALL').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ALL">
  <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=UP" alt="Arrow" id="Arrow_up" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=DOWN" alt="Arrow" id="Arrow_down" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

  <div id="Part_of_ALL">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)
  </div>

</div>
```